# MongoDB CSUUID Fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

A bit of a strange scenario, but I basically have a strongly typed model, lets call it Person. This model is saved into MongoDB using the C# driver. Then another application pulls out the raw BSON document (via QueryDocument) then calls ToJson() and spits it out somewhere else for something else to consume.

However the JSON spat out has custom CSUUID fields in the JSON and the serialization framework doesn't know how to deal with them, so is there any way to just remove them and have it just have the GUID without the CSUUID wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you do .ToJson() with an overload that takes JsonWriterSettings.  JsonWriterSettings has a property call OutputMode which corresponds to the JsonOutputMode.  With it, you can choose the level of "strictness" you want.

```
var settings = new JsonWriterSettings
{
  OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict
};

return doc.ToJson(settings);
```

Comment: I tried using that exact approach from the MongoDB docs, however it instead spat out the guid as some base64 style string, which although I guess removes the CSUUID it just replaces one problem with another, as ideally I just want: ` { some-guid: "0000-0000-..." }`, I tried some of the other modes and also tried changing the GuidRepresentation, but nothing seemed to output it like you would normally expect.

Comment: The only other way to handle that would be to store Guids as a native string.  If you are using POCOs, you can do that pretty easily by using a BsonRepresentation attribute.  Otherwise, you'll need to look into another Json library like Json.NET.